# Adding a directory of files to Hadoop using distributed cache?

Tags: java, hadoop, distributed-caching

I'm trying to add a bunch of dependencies stored on hdfs to distributed cache.  I've been following the advice from this article: http://www.datasalt.com/2011/05/handling-dependencies-and-configuration-in-java-hadoop-projects-efficiently/.  My question is: is it possible to add a folder containing the dependencies to the classpath?

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/tmp/lib/"), job.getConfiguration());
```

Or would I need to add each dependency individually?

```
for (Path dependency : dependencies) {
   DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(dependency, job.getConfiguration());
}
```

And how would I check that the dependencies were actually added to the classpath on all the slave nodes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate the jars and add them one at a time as you suggested. Or you can bundle the jars into a single zip file and then use the `DistributedCache.addArchiveToClassPath(Path, Configuration)` method.

To check they were added to the classpath, try examining the System property `java.class.path` in the setup method of a mapper / reducer.